# When extracting HTM its doesnt save data to file

Tags: imacros

I have problem in my code, that it only extracts data from variable id and doesn't extract the title. But if i remove extraction for id, title is saving,i guess that might be problem with my extraction for HTM.
Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
var i = 1;

while(iimPlayCode('SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1\nTAG POS='+i+' TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"pl-video-title-link*" CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER')>0) {

    iimPlayCode('TAG POS='+i+' TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"pl-video-title-link*" EXTRACT=TXT\n')
    var title = iimGetLastExtract();
    var title = title.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    iimSet('title',title);


    iimPlayCode('TAG POS='+i+' TYPE=TR ATTR=data-video-id:"*" EXTRACT=HTM\n')
    var id = iimGetLastExtract();
    var id = id.match(/data-video-id="(.+?)"/)[1];
    iimSet('id',id);

    iimPlayCode('SET !EXTRACT {{title}}\nSET !EXTRACT {{id}}\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Output_for_Youtube_Playlist.csv\n');
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i i figure it out, i forgot put space between single quotes for regex i think this was the issue and i remade structure of script

```
while(iimPlayCode('SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1\nTAG POS='+i+' TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"pl-video-title-link*" CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER')>0) {

    iimPlay('Code:'
        + 'TAG POS='+i+' TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"pl-video-title-link*" EXTRACT=TXT\n'
        + 'TAG POS='+i+' TYPE=TR ATTR=data-video-id:"*" EXTRACT=HTM\n'
    )

    var title = iimGetExtract(1);
    title = title.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

    var id = iimGetExtract(2);
    var id = id.match(/data-video-id="(.+?)"/)[1];

    saveRes = 'CODE:';
    saveRes += 'ADD !EXTRACT "'+title+'"' + '\n';
    saveRes += 'ADD !EXTRACT "'+id+'"' + '\n';
    saveRes += 'SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Output_for_Youtube_Playlist.csv\n';
    iimPlay(saveRes);
    i++;
}
```